# why is my java generic method cannot get two params?

Tags: java, generics, syntax

I have tried to write a java generic method.

```
private <T> setDefaultIfNull<T>(T setValue, T defaultVal) {
    return (setValue != null)? setValue : defaultVal;
}
```

Why is my syntax wrong?

It doesn't compolie

Comment: "It doesn't compile" is never enough information. Please provide the complete error message.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Correct syntax is that

```
private <T> T setDefaultIfNull(T setValue, T defaultVal) {
        return (setValue != null)? setValue : defaultVal;
    }
```

You added the parameter to the method as well :)